# In the SSIS Export package, How to rename the destination excel file with time stamp attached to it?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

In  the SSIS Export package,  How to rename the destination excel file with  time stamp attached to it?

I have Excel as my Destination file. How to rename the destination file with time stamp attached to its suffix?

such as myfile_010120191100.xls

Generating dynamic file name will help us to avoid overwriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did it a few days ago like that:

Use a File System Task Editor with Rename File operation. The picture below, I have a variable called FilePathTargetCopy, which is hard-coded like C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/aaa.xlsx. TEST_Copy is a "File Connection Manager" with "Create File" operation.

Create a similar File connection, go to its properties and add a ConnectionString expression with:

```
REPLACE(@[User::FilePathTargetCopy],".xlsx","")+"-"+
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),4)+"-"+
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) +"-"+
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2) + ".xlsx"
```

Then, set it as DestinationConnection with OverWrite=true as below.

[image]

Comment: Do i need to implement File System Task above the Data Flow Task? i.e Start from File System Task and then go to Data Flow Task .. ?

Comment: i need minutes as well

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable in your variable pane for FileName.

You can use Expressions to build a file name like this:

```
"FilePathHere\FileName_" +  (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + "" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + "" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY( GETDATE()), 2) + 
"_" + Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("hh",getdate()),2) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("mi",getdate()),".xlsx"
```

You can click Evaluate Expression to ensure it works and gives you the path you want.

Then in your flat file connection manager go to properties and click Expressions -> Connection String.

This is where you select the variable name above for your file name.

Adding note:
In the expression it is doing the RIGHT("0"..  on the string for the month so if it is a 1 digit month it will append a 0 in front of it (same for rest of them) so they will always be 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late but I always use a script task to set variables when it comes to datetime and setting expressions vs using variables. I find it easier to follow variables as expressions seem to get lost in the logic.

This table should help you out:

Date And Time Format In C# Programming

```
Format                                          E.g. Result
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")    05/29/2015 05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm")        05/29/2015 5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt")     05/29/2015 5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")    05/29/2015 05:50:06
```