# Getting an error running Eray's code from File System Task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

[File System Task] Error: File or directory "REPLACE(@[User::FilePathTargetCopy],".xml","")+"-"+RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),4)+"-"+Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) +"-"+Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2) + ".xml"" represented by connection "TEST_Copy" does not exist.

TEST_Copy Connection properties:
ConnectionString: REPLACE(@[User::FilePathTargetCopy],".xml","")+"-"+RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),4)+"-"+Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) +"-"+Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2) + ".xml"

Name:  TEST_Copy
Variable in Connection Manager:  D:...\EXPORT.xml
QualifiedName:  User::FilePathTargetCopy

I have the variables assigned as Eray suggests on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242258/181965 , have the Connection Manager set up the same as well but when running, it errors out.  I'm sure that it is a simple fix.

Comment: That looks like you've put a expression in a literal, not an expression property.

Comment: Could then you supply more than your response to fix the error?  I just copied Eray Balkanli's suggestion to resolve a renaming an existing file from a File System Task.

Comment: As in, you've dumped the expression in the connection string property, not the expressions property with the connection string option selected in the drop down.

Comment: *"I just copied Eray Balkanli's suggestion"* I have no idea what/who that is and where you got those instructions from; you don't cite that source in your question.

Comment: I sited the source in the original question, however for clarity I will post it again here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242258/181965.  I have copied everything that is mentioned in the source listed above and there is no movement on the solution except for the error message that is quoted.  I have no idea Thom what you are addressing as this is the first crack at renaming an existing file in an existing folder for archiving purpose.  Maybe you can direct me another way vice this way?

Comment: *"I sited the source in the original question"* Respectfully, you [did not](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77189499/1), someone else ( @billinkc ) appears to have found the source and edited the question for you.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your File System Task Editor to your question.

Comment: As Thom suggests, screenshots are exceptionally helpful when creating SSIS questions as values are ferreted about the UI. Win-Shift-S will bring up the screen snipping tool, copy the area in question to clipboard. Click the Edit button and paste it into your Question. I would find it helpful to have a screenshot of: the Connection Managers, Variables as well as the File System Task Editor which was already requested.